# LDA Doesn't distinguish more than one topic - what's going wrong?

Tags: r, nlp, lda

I've only recently started using LDA in my work, however, every time I have used LDA (in R), the topics returned are largely equivalent in top terms. Essentially, there is only one latent topic that can be distinguished from my results. This problem has occurred consistently on different data sets, of different topics and different origins. N.B all the data sets are in the 10,000s of rows - might be too small?

I'm using this code;

```
data_DL_dtm <- NPS_Clientidentified %>%
  filter(!is.na(Comment)) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, Comment) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  anti_join(custom_stop_words) %>%
  count(`Full Name`, word) %>%
  cast_dtm(`Full Name`, word, n)
nrow(data_DL_tidy)
DL_lda <- LDA(data_DL_dtm, k = 3, control = list(seed = 1234))

DL_topics <- tidy(DL_lda, matrix="beta")
DL_top_terms <- DL_topics %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  top_n(10, beta) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(topic, -beta)

DL_top_terms %>%
  mutate(term = reorder(term, beta)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(term, beta, fill = factor(topic))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

Which gives me this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5URC.png

I wouldn't expect that the system would appear as the top term for every topic.

Am I missing something here? OR is there some way to improve my LDA models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your topics converged there are three reasons this might happen:

1. you are likely iterating too many times
2. you are passing over the corpus too many times
3. low data volume - 10,000 rows is small my LDAs' are typically trained on 1.5 -1.7 million rows.  I get low coherence on 300,000 or less, but not converging topics

I hope this helps :)